# Convert View to UIView in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiview

My current method of accomplishing this seems hackish, so I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. Here's what I have so far:

For this ContentView that returns a `View`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
let context: DeviceActivityReport.Context = .totalActivity
let filter = DeviceActivityFilter(
    segment:.daily(
        during: DateInterval(
            start: Date().addingTimeInterval(-24 * 3600),
            end: Date()
        )
    )
)

var body: some View {
    DeviceActivityReport(context, filter:filter)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 250.0)
}}
```

To convert it to an UIView, I am using UIHostingController + UIViewController:

```
public class FluffView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {

let frame: CGRect
let viewId: Int64

init(_ frame: CGRect, viewId: Int64, args: Any?) {
    self.frame = frame
    self.viewId = viewId
}

let context: DeviceActivityReport.Context = .totalActivity
let filter = DeviceActivityFilter(
    segment:.daily(
        during: DateInterval(
            start: Date().addingTimeInterval(-24 * 3600),
            end: Date()
        )
    )
)


public func view() -> UIView {
    var child = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
    var parent = UIViewController()
    child.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    child.view.frame = parent.view.bounds
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        child.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.topAnchor),
        child.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.leadingAnchor),
        child.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.bottomAnchor),
        child.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.trailingAnchor)
    ])
    // First, add the view of the child to the view of the parent
    parent.view.addSubview(child.view)
    // TODO: set background color here
    // parent.view.backgroundColor = BackgroundStyle()
    // Then, add the child to the parent
    parent.addChild(child)
    
    return parent.view
}
```

}

However, the result I get results in a black box around it with a super weird formatting:
[image]

(by the way, the reason I need UIVIew is so I can pass it to [Flutter's Platform Channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels))

Update:

with Nikita's solution, I am getting a:

Thread 1: "Unable to activate constraint with anchors `<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x283032200 \"_TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewV6Runner11ContentView_:0x10506aa00.top\"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x2830320c0 \"UIView:0x1043cfa00.top\"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."`

This is happening on the second line of this code (I believe it is because I am using AppDelegate from Flutter):

```
    @UIApplicationMain
    @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    
    
    let viewFactory = FluffViewFactory()

    // this calls FluffView above which leads to view() that converts the view to a UIView
    registrar(forPlugin: "Kitty")?.register(viewFactory, withId: "FluffView")


    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's the only way of using `View` inside `UIView` - `UIHostingController`.

Your parent view's frame is invalid here:

```
child.view.frame = parent.view.bounds
```

so it's better to active layout constraints instead:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    child.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.topAnchor),
    child.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.leadingAnchor),
    child.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.bottomAnchor),
    child.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.view.trailingAnchor)
])
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm using Flutter's AppDelegate so with the above code I'm getting a:

"Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x283f2a080 \"_TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewV6Runner11ContentView_:0x10a817600.top\"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x283f28880 \"UIView:0x109f59a80.top\"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."

I'm updating my question with more of my code and the error

Comment: @TejasSharma you need to activate constraints after addSubview